# In date-picker a dropdown disappears when I put a date with days

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

This example works fine when I use only month (the dropdown doesn't disappear):

http://jsfiddle.net/dT6AU/

But when I try to configure days, the dropdown disappears. I changed the date format to dd-mm-yyyy:

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
     language: 'es',
     format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
     viewMode: "days",
     minViewMode: "days",
     autoclose: true
  });
```

And added span.days to the function that stopPropagation.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what changes did you make?

Comment: I understand your problem. The dropdown is closing, not disappearing...

Comment: stopPropagation on td.day

Comment: can you explain it better?

Answer (score 2):

in days mode, the `stopPropagation` should be called on `td.day` click

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
     language: 'es',
     format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
     viewMode: "days",
     minViewMode: "days",
     autoclose: true
  });

$(document).on('click', 'td.day, th.next, th.prev, th.switch, span.year', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```